# .htaccess on Zeus web server

Tags: .htaccess, zeus

Can anyone give me an example of what a .htaccess file should look like on a server running Zues?

The one I copied from an Apache server doesn't work. I get a HTTP 403 when I try to access the directory, no prompt for username/password.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile ../pathto/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The path to my .htpasswd file was wrong.